# How to get the first and last values from the dataframe column using a function

Tags: python, pandas

I need to get the first value and last values for the following using a function similar to the way I'm getting the `max()` and `min()` values from a Pandas DF column.  So this part of my code works perfectly to give me the max and min:

```
day_high = day_session['High'].rolling(window=1,freq='D').max()
day_low = day_session['Low'].rolling(window=1,freq='D').min()
```

How do I get the first and last values respectively here using a function?

`day_open = day_session.Open.rolling(window=1,freq='D').`? (what is the 'first' function?)

`day_close = day_session.Last.rolling(window=1,freq='D').`? (what is the 'last' function?)

I already tried `.first()` and this gives error output '`Rolling' object has no attribute 'first'` and same for `.last()`

This is an example of the data Im using:

```
data['Last']
Out[96]:
Timestamp
2013-03-07 09:30:00    1440.00
2013-03-07 09:31:00    1439.75
2013-03-07 09:32:00    1440.50
2013-03-07 09:33:00    1441.00
2013-03-07 09:34:00    1441.50
2013-03-07 09:35:00    1441.75
2013-03-07 09:36:00    1440.75
2013-03-07 09:37:00    1440.50
2013-03-07 09:38:00    1440.75
2013-03-07 09:39:00    1440.00
```

This code is used for the rolling window and works fine for the max() Min() above:

```
daystart = '9:30'
dayend = '16:14:59'

day_session = data.between_time(daystart,dayend, include_start=True, include_end=True)
```

I am using concat to utilise this data with other series data in a df called `all_vals`

```
all_vals = pd.concat([day_open,day_close,day_high,day_low,day_range,IB_high,IB_low,IB_Range,upper_quartile,lower_quartile,end_session_high,end_session_low], axis=1)
```

thanks

Answer (score 7):

select the first and last value of a particular column of a data frame

```
df['column_name'].iloc[0] # first element 
df['column_name'].iloc[-1] # last element
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to resample using [`ohlc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ohlc.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ohlc)?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'price': [100, 101, 102, 103]},
    index=pd.to_datetime(['2016-07-08 10:00', '2016-07-08 10:00', '2016-07-08 10:00', '2016-07-08 10:00']))

>>> df.resample('D', how={'price': 'ohlc'})
           price                
            open high  low close
2016-07-08   100  103  100   103
```

You should generally post questions with some sample data and expected results.

**EDIT**
Given your sample data, you can do this:

```
df.resample('D', how={'Last': 'ohlc'})
            Last                        
            open     high      low close
Timestamp                               
2013-03-07  1440  1441.75  1439.75  1440
```

Comment: Im not sure how I could use the resample in this context.  I have added additional data to the post above.  I will now also upload the data.

Comment: I appreciate your response and I will upload additional data as mentioned before but the code is part of a bigger piece and I need to think about how to extract the relevant data.  
The main area of code where this is taken from is shown above.
Im not sure how doing the resample you mention would populate all the rows as per the rolling min() and max() I'm using for the other rows in the df Im sending this data to.
I thought it would be easy to extract the first and last prices via `.rolling` but I must be wrong.

Comment: Also, which version of Pandas are you using.  The functionality of `.rolling` changed significantly in v. 0.18.

Comment: pd.__version__ '0.18.0'

Comment: Also, given that you are using a one day frequency in your rolling window, and that you have max and min and now you want first and last, it appears to me that you _really_ want OHLC.  Is there something else you are after?

Comment: Your idea looks to have worked when I used the following code: `d1_day = day_session.Last.resample('D', how='ohlc')
d1_day = day_session.Open.resample('D', how='ohlc')
day_open = d1_day.open
day_close = d1_day.close` `all_vals['day_close'] = day_close
all_vals['day_open'] = day_open` I will mark up the answer but would still like to hear of other ways to do this using rolling.

Comment: Ahhh... You are using open and close values for each bar.  Your max and min values won't be correct, because you are only taking the max of the close values instead of all values that occurred within the bar.

Comment: Sorry its late.  Is this better? `d1_day_close = day_session.Last.resample('D', how='ohlc')
d1_day_open = day_session.Open.resample('D', how='ohlc')
day_open = d1_day_open.open
day_close = d1_day_close.close`  Please note I will still use min max with previous rolling code and only using resample for daily open and close.